# Jquery .push not increasing length of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am building a Match Game and I am stuck trying to pass the card values to an empty array that will check if the numbers match once the array's length = 2. As I log the values of $flippedCards, I see that the card value hasn't been pushed to it and its length is still 0.

```
$('.card').click(function() {
 MatchGame.flipCard($(this),$('#game'))
});


MatchGame.flipCard = function($card, $game) {

    var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards', []);

    console.log($card.data('flipped')); 
    console.log($card.data('value')); 
    console.log($card.data('color')); 

    if ($card.data('flipped')) {

        console.log('card already flipped'); 
        console.log($flippedCards);
        return;

    } else {

        $card.data('flipped', true);
        $card.css('background-color', $card.data('color'));
        $card.text($card.data('value'));
        $card.css('background-image', null);
        $flippedCards.push($card.data('value'));

        console.log($flippedCards);
    }

};
```

the project is also available here https://github.com/liviarett/matchgame

Comment: please provide all relevant code when asking questions.  I don't see a call to `push` in the code above

Comment: `$flippedCards.push($card.data('value'));` is there, but is it being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you actually set the data attribute here:

```
var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards', []);
```

jQuery is all about chaining, so it actually returns you $game when you do $game.data('filppedCards', []):

```
 $game.data('flippedCards', []) === $game // true
```

You might be interested in setting the data attribute somewhere before, maybe in the `renderCards` method. And set $flippedCards without the value parameter:

```
var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards');
```

UPD: you already have it in the renderCards method actually:

```
$game.empty();
$game.data('flippedCards', []);
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept everything as was (initialised it in renderCards), but updated var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards', []); to var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards'); and it seems to be working!! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I cloned and ran through your code. It seems like you are initializing a new `var $flippedCards = $game.data('flippedCards', []);` everytime, you probably want to either initialize it else where and make it a global variable or pass it in as a parameter, or else, it'll reinitialize it as a new variable, that's why it is not incrementing as you wanted it to.